# How to avoid ill-conditioned covariance systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, covariance, condition-number

A well-known issue with linear systems defined by covariance functions is that of ill-conditioning [[Mohammadi et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.00853.pdf), [Ababou et al. 1992](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02065878)]. The solution to this issue is usually preconditioning (e.g. add a noise to the diagonal, or do something more sophisticated). However, I would like to understand better the root of the illness of such systems based on a simple toy example.

Suppose we are given a set of 10 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, all stacked in a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 10}$:

$$
X =
\begin{bmatrix}
93.0 & 90.0 & 89.0 & 94.0 & 93.0 & 97.0 & 95.0 & 88.0 & 96.0 & 98.0 \\
40.0 & 33.0 & 34.0 & 36.0 & 30.0 & 39.0 & 39.0 & 28.0 & 25.0 & 35.0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and a target location $x_o = \begin{bmatrix}97.0 \\ 32.0\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Visually, the matrix and target location encode a spatial arrangement of points in the plane:

[image: spatial arrangement of points]

Given a covariance function like $cov(x,y) = e^{-\left(\frac{||x-y||}{20}\right)^2}$, we can evaluate it pairwise between all points in $X$, and produce a covariance matrix $C \in S_+^{10\times 10}$:

$$
C =
\begin{bmatrix}
1.0 & 0.865022 & 0.878095 & 0.95839 & 0.778801 & 0.95839 & 0.987578 & 0.655406 & 0.557106 & 0.882497 \\
0.865022 & 1.0 & 0.995012 & 0.939413 & 0.955997 & 0.80856 & 0.858559 & 0.930066 & 0.778801 & 0.843665 \\
0.878095 & 0.995012 & 1.0 & 0.930066 & 0.923116 & 0.800515 & 0.858559 & 0.911649 & 0.722527 & 0.814647 \\
0.95839 & 0.939413 & 0.930066 & 1.0 & 0.911649 & 0.955997 & 0.97531 & 0.778801 & 0.731616 & 0.95839 \\
0.778801 & 0.955997 & 0.923116 & 0.911649 & 1.0 & 0.784664 & 0.80856 & 0.930066 & 0.918512 & 0.882497 \\
0.95839 & 0.80856 & 0.800515 & 0.955997 & 0.784664 & 1.0 & 0.99005 & 0.603506 & 0.611097 & 0.95839 \\
0.987578 & 0.858559 & 0.858559 & 0.97531 & 0.80856 & 0.99005 & 1.0 & 0.65377 & 0.611097 & 0.939413 \\
0.655406 & 0.930066 & 0.911649 & 0.778801 & 0.930066 & 0.603506 & 0.65377 & 1.0 & 0.833185 & 0.68901 \\
0.557106 & 0.778801 & 0.722527 & 0.731616 & 0.918512 & 0.611097 & 0.611097 & 0.833185 & 1.0 & 0.771052 \\
0.882497 & 0.843665 & 0.814647 & 0.95839 & 0.882497 & 0.95839 & 0.939413 & 0.68901 & 0.771052 & 1.0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The condition number of this covariance matrix is $1.175329314060857e6$.

1. Is there any study or strategy for improving the condition number by looking at the spatial arrangement of the points in $X$? Suppose that we are allowed to discard some of the points.
2. How to identify the points in $X$ that are causing the system to be ill-conditioned?

If we attempt to solve the system $Cw = c$ where $c$ is the covariance between all points in $X$ and $x_o$, the solution can be quite wrong, and this is only due to the numerical issue described above.

I appreciate if you have any recommendations or publications addressing this issue.

Comment: Someone may have a nice answer for you, and I hope they do, but the issue with trying to visualise the ill-conditioning using points in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ is that this isn't where the degenerate behaviour really is, instead the issue is degeneracy of the multivariate normal - so an issue might be the ellipsises of the multivariate normal in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ are concentrated on some lower dimensional subspace and obviously that isn't so easy to visualise

Comment: another, potentially instructive example and somewhat easier to visualise, is to take a Gaussian Process and the RKHS associated with it and then take a function not in this RKHS and try and fit it

Comment: @Nadiels thank you for your comments. The issue is definitely a function of the covariance function. I'd like to add that I've tried with other kernels such as exponential, and spherical (with the same range of 20) and they are still ill-conditioned. The worst of all is the Gaussian kernel illustrated in the question.

Comment: Preconditioning with noise along the diagonal is known as the ridge covariance matrix (or Tikhonov regularization). Why not use, and how would that compare with, the matrix exponential, which is always positive-definite for symmetric matrices: $$e^C = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} C^k$$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73126/if-a-is-symmetric-then-ea-is-positive-definite