# How to prove that the element-wise exponential of a symmetric matrix is not always positive-definite?

Tags: exponentiation, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, matrix-exponential

The [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) $e^X$ of a square symmetric matrix $X$ [is always positive-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73126/if-a-is-symmetric-then-ea-is-positive-definite), where $$
e^X = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} X^k
$$

Does the exponentiation of each *element* of the symmetric matrix $X$ (**not to be confused with the matrix exponential above**) also result in a positive-definite matrix?

$$\begin{pmatrix}
e^{x_1} & e^{x_{1,2}} & e^{x_{1,3}}\\
e^{x_{2,1}} & e^{x_2} & e^{x_{2,3}}\\
e^{x_{3,1}} & e^{x_{3,2}} & e^{x_3} 
\end{pmatrix}\neq e^X$$

After experimentally running this new question (different than the original question that was closed) with toy data, **I am seeing that the element-wise exponential  matrix is not always positive-definite** like how the matrix exponential always is. but I could be wrong.

How can we prove that the element-wise exponential matrix does not guarantee positive-definiteness? (please general mathematical proofs only, rather than a counter-example)

Comment: Just give a counter example. Already $[-1 \ \ 0 // 0\ \ 0 ]$ does the job.

Comment: counter-example of what? and what job does that do? sorry but there were a number of statements made/asked in the question so I don't know to which you are referring

Comment: It's a symmetric matrix for which the component-wise exponential is not positive definite and thus the prove you asked for in your final question.

Comment: ok thanks for the counter-example. i was looking for a mathematical proof that extends to any matrix component-wise though, but i know you know. Why hasn't this changed question been re-opened yet?

Comment: "How can we prove that the element-wise exponential matrix does not guarantee positive-definiteness?" Such a statement you DO prove typically by giving a counter example. You need to modify you question if you were hoping for something else. Your statement is not wrong in general either. I guess you will find matrices for which the componentwise exponetial is positive definite.

Comment: sorry if i sounded like I was trying to be smart, and was even worried it would be taken in such a way, which it did. i just wanted to differentiate mathematical proofs from counter-examples. for example, I consider the following a proof that the matrix exponential is positive-definite, and it is by no means a counter-example: $$ x^Te^Ax=x^Te^{A/2}e^{A/2}x=x^T(e^{A/2})^Te^{A/2}x=\lVert e^{A/2}x\rVert\geq 0$$ I have updated the last paragraph in the question to avoid the same confusion

Comment: But the logic behind the statements is entirly different! Above you wanted to prove that something is TRUE FOR ALL symmetric matrices. Now in you post you want to prove that some thing is not NOT TRUE IN GENERAL FOR ALL symmetric matrices. 'Not true in general for all' means you need to find AT LEAST ONE for which it is not true. This is what the counter example does. There is no general prove similar to the one you gave above in this setting. ...

Comment: ... What you can likely do is, at least in the $2\times 2$ setting, provide necessary and sufficient criteria on the coefficients of the matirx which ensure that the entrywise exponential is positive/negative/in- definite. But that's another question.