# Applications of the weighted matrix exponential $x^\top e^A x$ (a quadratic function)

Tags: statistics, convex-optimization, exponentiation, symmetric-matrices, matrix-exponential

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73126/if-a-is-symmetric-then-ea-is-positive-definite), the matrix exponential $$e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} A^k$$ of any symmetric matrix $A$ was proven to be positive-definite based on the quadratic function $$x^\top e^A x$$ where $x$ are weights that could sum to 1, I don't know.

In what sort of empirical applications is this weighted matrix exponential, $ x^\top e^A x$,  even used?

Comment: What do you mean by "empirical applications"?

Comment: For any symmetric matrix $M$, the function $Q(x) = x^\top Mx$ defines a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), which seems to be the kind of thing you're asking about

Comment: yes, quadratic programming problems from any scientific discipline involving the matrix exponential would do

Comment: Controllability Gramian may be an example from Control Theory.

Comment: in controllability gramian, what are the properties of *x*? are they weights that sum to 1

Comment: @develarist Naturally, no.

Comment: It's not expedient to think of $x$ as weights here. The $x$s are nothing you choose in this setting, but rather you've got to prove that $x^{\top}Mx\ge0$ FOR ALL $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. That's how you prove/define a matrix being positive definite in the first place.

Comment: We're looking beyond just the application of proving the matrix exponential's positive-definiteness. So it's not so much about *choosing* $x$, but the *optimization* of $x$ for whatever application this objective function has a purpose for, $$\arg \min_x \, x^\top e^A x  $$

Comment: If you restrict the minimisation to the unit simplex then this is basically a quadratic knapp sack problem. Moreover, if $A$ is symmetric the minimisers will be evolutionary stable strategies for the replicator dynamic associated to $e^{A}$.